# Set Warranty Bit: Kernel

Tags: rom-flashing, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-5, reboot

So whenever I boot up my device or restart it I see a little yellow message in the top left corner of the screen that reads "Set Warranty Bit: Kernel." I have researched this issue and learned that I must reflash the firmware of the phone.

That being said. If I reflash the correct firmware for the same model for the same carrier, will my phone still have service following the procedure? Or will I have to work with my carrier to reactivate my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you don't need to worry.

Provided you pay your bills, your carrier does not care much, if at all, that you root/ flash Roms and such. No extra steps will have to be taken either; its all on the sim, and flashing ignores that. Keep note you have lost your warranty, though!

Comment: Well it is a CDMA phone so that really isn't correct either. The answer here is flashing reinstalls the bootloader and does not affect the regular operation of the OS be it programs, files, and settings.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi it depends on what you are flashing :) However, provided your SIM card works, and provided you have an IMEI (in /efs) you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have that message most likely because you flashed a custom ROM and/or kernel which cannot pass Samsung's verification. Don't worry about it if your phone functions fine right now - it only influences warranty (as the message says), and you only need to consider reflashing when you want that message gone so you can get warranty.