# Soft-Bricked Samsung Galaxy S5 - "Set Warranty Bit: Kernel"

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I recently did some stuff to my Samsung Galaxy S5 UK (SM-G900F) on Three and Marshmallow 6.0.1:
(In order)

1. Successfully install TWRP using Odin
2. Successfully root using Chainfire's Systemless Root
3. The message 'Set Warranty Bit: Kernel' starts appearing on the Samsung Android logo during boot, but it still works fine. (I think this means I voided my warranty.)
4. Successfuly install BusyBox using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.busybox&hl=en)
5. Install XPosed Framework ArmV7 version, following a guide I can't find any more, but I got my file from the official XDA thread

Now when I rebooted my phone after installing XPosed, it gets stuck on the Samsung Android logo with the 'Set Warranty Bit: kernel' message. I can get to TWRP by (steps, not methods):

1. Removing and replacing the battery
2. Plugging in the charger
3. When the battery charging animation shows, pressing Home+Power+VolUp

What I would like to know is:

- Should I restore it using Odin?
- If so, with a Stock or Custom ROM?
- If not, how is it recoverable?

Comment: Yes, you have triggered *Knox* and got that warning // [Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/154155). I would suggest to uninstall Xposed , flash original stuck ROM of correct version using Odin first before trying Xposed again (research for correct version and process) // You can wait for inputs from other users of the device / problem to respond but IMO suggested steps are safe

Comment: FYI, `Set warranty bit: kernel` is normal if you have modified the OS.

Comment: `Set Warranty Bit: Kernel` is a message that appears when you mess up with... your kernel. Such kernel is contained in the **boot.img** file, and is exactly what **Systemless Root** alters to offer its functionalities. It's also highly probable that you did trip KNOX as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung phones require a special version of Xposed -  the regular one just won't work as you experienced.

Since you can still get into TWRP, the situation is still under control. Uninstall the current one with the uninstaller from the [official Xposed thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811), try booting up, and if it returns to normal, download and install the [special version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960).

Comment: This worked, thanks; unfortunately all my data was wiped, including the backup file of my data. It's not hugely important, just a bit annoying.

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't have. Anyways the damage is done, so just keep it in mind next time :)