# Stuck in boot loop after doing a factory reset, uploading custom firmware (via Odin), rebooting and doing another factory reset

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, boot-loop, odin

I have the same issue as descibed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154155/set-warranty-bit-kerne/154224#154224?newreg=cef3994465fe45f9b53da05dac6bfdcd). I got the firmware file from [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s5/SM-G900FD/SER/confirm/G900FDXXS1CQD1/130436/).

My phone isn't recognized by my computer when I connect it to USB ports that other devices work with while connected to the same ports. (The error popup notification from Windows Explorer is "This device malfunctioned and Windows can't connect to it".) The phone shows charging icon when connected by cable to a power socket. So while I tried to follow the following steps, I got stuck. Since there does not seem to be a connection between the phone and the computer, the flash won't complete.

1. Extract (unzip) the firmware file
2. Download Odin v3.12.3
3. Extract Odin ZIP file
4. Open Odin v3.12.3
5. Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
6. Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
7. Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
8. Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked
9. Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes

This is a screen shot of my interaction with Odin.

[image: Odin interaction]

Other than getting a new phone, do you have any tips on how to fix this?

I tested a cable with another device, and it worked with that device.

I then tried again with that cable and the same port.

[image]

[image]

OK I got Odin to pass. I just had to make sure that it was connected properly and the MD5 file was added by clicking in the AP box and opening the file rather than dragging and dropping it into the box. Once I did that it started to download.

[image]

However, the phone is still stuck in a boot loop.

I am now able to connect to PC (Odin) but not able to make it boot.

I did a factory reset and rebooted, but I still get the same thing—it won't get past the boot screen.

Comment: Go to recovery mode manually by using Home + Power + Volume Up, then try a factory reset from there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I already tried that.

Comment: I tried again. Holding those buttons down, it would keep rebooting. If I held them down until the boot screen appeared, the screen would stay stuck there after I released it.

Comment: OK after a few minutes it went to recovery mode.

Comment: I did a factory reset and rebooted, but I still get the same thing.

Comment: Not what I expected. Considering that you're now able to connect to PC (Odin) but not able to make it boot instead, I suggest making some (drastic) edits to the question so it reflects your current situation better.

Comment: OK I've updated the question.